# Standalone spark on Windows 10

Tags: java, apache-spark

Using [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html) guide to get a Standalone. But whenever I perform the "sbin\start-master.sh" command, a new CMD window pops up and then disappears immediately. No URL is being printed.

I've done the initial setup and set all the environment variables properly but it still doesn't seem to work. How can I fix this?

Edit: Also tried [this](https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/04/02/setting-up-a-spark-project-with-maven.html) example using Intelli-J. Its showing the following without any other output:

```
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @568ms
[Thread-0] INFO spark.webserver.JettySparkServer - == Spark has ignited ...
[Thread-0] INFO spark.webserver.JettySparkServer - >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.3.2.v20150730
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@e92ccd{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4567}
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @942ms
```

Comment: That is shell script doesn't work on windows machine..

Comment: .sh won't work on windows. See if there exists .cmd

Comment: No there are no .cmd files in the whole "sbin" folder.